# Displaying different content depending on which title it has

Tags: django, django-templates, jinja2

I am creating a django application with classed based views. In the detail view, I want depending on the title the object has, show different content. I don't understand why the if statement does not work. The data in the example is just dummy data right now because it is in the development stage.

This shows the detail view I have created.

```
{% extends 'main.html' %}

{% block content %}
<div class="container px-5">
    {{object.title}}


    {% if object.title == 'hello' %}
    {% include 'x/y.html' %}
    {% endif %}


</div>


{% endblock content %}
```

Does anybody know how I can fix this?

This is my TEMPLATES DIR setting.

```
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [
        BASE_DIR / 'templates'
    ],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ],
    },
},
```

]

And my y/x.html is stored in the same directory as the detail page. In this case, the directory is "y".

Comment: Can you show your TEMPLATE DIRS settings ? And is your x/y.html stored at that location ?

Comment: @barbaart I have now added the templates settings.

Comment: allright, now you have to create the folder 'templates' inside the BASE_DIR (your projects folder). Put your x/y.html inside that and it should work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd make sure your `TEMPLATES and BASE_DIR` variables in your `settings.py` file look something like this:

```
from pathlib import Path

BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [str(BASE_DIR.joinpath('templates'))], # new
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Comment: Thank you, I am on my mobile right now, will try it out tomorrow and tell you the result!

Comment: Awesome @AdrianMahdavian I hope it works for you!